# Getting ArrayIndexOutofBoundException:0 while assigning value to array

Tags: java, arrays, exception

When I'm trying to assign value to my array in jsp, I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0

Below is my code,

```
String[] imgarray = {};
int ival = 0;

// Below code in a while loop 
imgarray[ival] = iname; // Value of iname is 1.jpg, 87.jpg, 114.jpg etc...
ival++;
```

Please let me know if i'm doing something wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are not dynamically grows as like Collections. So you have to give size of the array before adding the elements to it.

```
String[] imgarray = new String[10];
int ival = 0;

// Below code in a while loop 
imgarray[ival] = iname; // Value of iname is 1.jpg, 87.jpg, 114.jpg etc...
ival++;
```

This should work.

Comment: Ramesh, I tried your solution. But, it results in java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

Comment: Of course. You need to set the size of the array to the number of elements it is going to hold. Ramesh chose 10 at random.

Comment: I'm not sure about the number of elements, but its guaranteed to be less than 60.                                                       When I write, String[] imgarray = new String[60]; It results in java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 60

Comment: This mean you’re adding more than 60 elements to your array. Maybe because of a bug in your loop you keep adding the same element over and over.

Comment: Yeah, it was my mistake. The number of elements was around 70 and it was resulting in exception. Thank you Etienne & Ramesh.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance how many elements your array is going to hold, then you should set the size of the array at creation time, as said Ramesh, since the size of an array cannot change after creation.

If you don’t know in advance how many elements your array will have to hold, then you need another structure. I suggest an ArrayList:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
// int ival = 0 <- not needed with a List

// below code in a while loop
list.add(iname);
// ival++
```